# How to enqueue the style using wp_enqueue_style()

Tags: wp-enqueue-style

I'm developing a theme. I added the codes (below) into the `header.php`. But I posted it into the WP theme repository, and it's under review, and the reviewer informed me to enqueue the style with `wp_enqueue_style()`/ `wp_enqueue_script()`. But can't understand how to implement it with the function. I've seen the directed [`wp_enqueue_style();`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) in Codex, but can't understand how to put the whole bunch of codes with their conditions.

```
<style type="text/css">
<?php
// If the menu presents, then CSS loads

if ( has_nav_menu( 'secondary' ) ) {
?>
.sec-menu{
width: 100%;
background: #333;
height: 26px;
font-size:16px;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
<?php } ?>
<?php
if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {
?>
#access{
background-color: #333;
height: 26px;
}
<?php } ?>
<?php
if ( !has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) && !has_nav_menu( 'secondary' ) ) {
?>
.sec-menu,
#access{
border-bottom: 2px solid #333;
}
<?php } ?>
</style>
```

- HOW TO?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is what you could do:

1 - Put the CSS in a separate file and save it in your theme directory.
2 - Add the following code in your `functions php`:

```
function wpse_89494_enqueue_scripts() {
  if ( has_nav_menu( 'secondary' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 
      'wpse_89494_style_1', 
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/your-style_1.css' 
    );
  }
  if ( has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 
      'wpse_89494_style_2', 
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/your-style_2.css' 
    );
  }
  if ( ! has_nav_menu( 'primary' ) && ! has_nav_menu( 'secondary' ) ) {
    wp_enqueue_style( 
      'wpse_89494_style_3', 
      get_template_directory_uri() . '/your-style_3.css' 
    );
  }
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_89494_enqueue_scripts' );
```

Comment: Why not put the conditionals inside the `wp_enqueue_scripts` callback? None of that needs to go in the document head.

Comment: I didn't think of that, a edit is on the way

Comment: +1. I edited to replace `get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' )` with `get_template_directory_uri()`. References to **stylesheet** directory should be reserved for Child Themes.

Comment: Nice & Fine. It solved me here. Thanks Mike. I'll add this thread into [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style), inshALLAH. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding a second `style.css` file for category page archives.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpsites_second_style_sheet' );
function wpsites_second_style_sheet() {
    if ( is_category() ) {
       wp_register_style( 'second-style', get_template_directory_uri() .'css/second-style.css', array(), '20130608');
       wp_enqueue_style( 'second-style' );    
    }    
}
```